# How to convert an object to the serialized syntax for data in jquery.ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, serialization

I have an object that I want to send with my jquery.ajax function but I can't find anything that will convert it to the serialized format I need.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'www.example.com',
  data: MyObject,
  success: function(data) {
    $('.data').html(data)
  }
})

MyObject = [
  {
    "UserId": "2",
    "UserLevel": "5",
    "FirstName": "Matthew"
  },
  {
    "UserId": "4",
    "UserLevel": "5",
    "FirstName": "Craig"
  }
]

Serialized_format = [
  {
    "name": "UserId",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "UserLevel",
    "value": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "FirstName",
    "value": "Craig"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hum... what is the serialized format you need? What is `MyObject` like?  Meaning: **What** do you **have** and **what** do you **want**? If you want JSON, then it is just `JSON.stringify(MyObject)` (and you probably have to assign it to a parameter, so `"parameter=" + JSON.stringify(...)"` ).

Comment: What language do you using on server side?

Comment: PHP, I tried the object the way it is above and it was just undefined when I did print_r($_POST). So I tried the same info with the serialized format and it worked

Comment: Your "serialized" version (it is not serialized btw) does not make sense. Does there exist a mapping at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I will put my comment as an answer then. If you want to transmit the array to the server side, you could transform it into JSON (at least this would be the easiest way imo).

Use [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'www.example.com',
  data: {paramter: JSON.stringify(MyObject)},
  success: function(data) {
    $('.data').html(data)
  }
});
```

where `parameter` is the name of the POST parameter you want to use.

`JSON.stringify` will give you a string like:

```
'[{"UserId":"2","UserLevel":"5","FirstName":"Matthew"},{"UserId":"4","UserLevel":"5","FirstName":"Craig"}]'
```

Retrieving on the server side, e.g. with PHP and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['parameter']);
```

would give you back an array of objects:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UserId] => 2
            [UserLevel] => 5
            [FirstName] => Matthew
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UserId] => 4
            [UserLevel] => 5
            [FirstName] => Craig
        ) 
)
```

---

I also suggest to rename `MyObject` to something meaningful which reflects the content of the variable. In fact, you have an array, not an object (yes, I know arrays are objects too).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to serialize, .ajax with type 'post' send the attributes of "MyObject" like as html POST to your script in 'url' parameter.

For example, in PHP:
Use:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'www.example.com/receive.php',
  data: {
      param1: 'test',
      param2: 123456
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('.data').html(data)
  }
})
```

In receive.php I have `$_POST['param1']` and `$_POST['param2']`.

Comment: how do you send the attributes as html post in the url?

Comment: The data would be send in the body of the request, not appended to the URL. That is GET.